# suddenly lost Network Access ubuntu 22.10

Tags: networking, xorg, 22.10

I was casually restarting my computer and the login was only proposed me through the shell, not the UI.
After reviewing this eventual infinite loop bug, I proceeded in uninstalling ubuntu-desktop to reinstall it just after, but then I noticed that I couldnt reinstall it because I couldnt get the apt package : the ubuntu.ethz.ch was failing. so I tried to ping 8.8.8.8 and the result is that the network is unreachable (i connect through ethernet and plugging it in my other desktop works).
So Here I am with a desktop that cannot connect to the internet thus cannot reinstall the package.
`ip addr` gives me 2 devices:
1: lo
2: enp0s31f6 which has state DOWN.
All my attempts to revive the network card are fruitless.
I did try to remove the firewall but the command ufw cannot be found. So I am a bit lost. Any idea? regards

Comment: Can you boot from an Ubuntu live installation USB and use the Try Ubuntu option? Do you have internet access from there? If so use chroot and install the desktop. This may not fix the network problem.

Comment: Have you considered USB tethering with your smartphone? It won't resolve the issue but it should grant you internet access in order to install the packages you need.

Comment: as long as the  ```ip a``` command does not show a ' NO-CARRIER' you can do a ```ip link set dev enp0s31f6 up ``` then call dhclient ```dhclient enp0s31f6```

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me was to install netplan.io and then follow along.
Then suddenly, the card seemed to work. AFAIK netplan is just a utility that make sure the configuration are correctly set up? What is frustrationg is I dont know what happened, neither what and How I fixed it.
I Have a feeling my network card is a bit more sluggish now so I am still looking for a solution where I make sure my network card is correctly configured and uses the right driver. I have a dell precision 3650. regards